# armature disappeared in animation panel only, shows up in other panels

Tags: animation, rigging

[image]

Not sure why this is occuring. I checked every toggle I could find! And none appeared to be wrong.

Tried option + h in pose mode.

I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 2):

You are in Local view, it means you have selected an object and pressed <kbd>/</kbd> to isolate, press <kbd>/</kbd> again to exit:

[image]